# Bootstrap: colapse accordion does not work

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm new to html/css stuff and while i'm trying a couple of tutorials, i end up with a problem when  trying to use accordion example from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/. I think the problem is with the css file. The .button class overwrites html code and causes the problem.

This is my html code:

```
        <section class="our-news section-margin">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="one-title" data-dsn-animate="up">
                    <div class="title-sub-container">
                        <p class="title-sub">Frequently Asked Questions</p>
                    </div>
                    <h2 class="title-main">What you need to know</h2>
                </div>

            <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                  <h2 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                      Collapsible Group Item #1
                    </button>
                  </h2>
                </div>

                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

css code.

```
.button,
button:not([data-filter]):not(.mfp-arrow),
input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #090909;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  line-height: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 20px 41px;
  margin-top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  -o-transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button:before,
button:not([data-filter]):not(.mfp-arrow):before,
input[type="button"]:before,
input[type="reset"]:before,
input[type="submit"]:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.2);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

What might be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Include the following in your html .
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you need to add the appropriate jquery scripts along with your bootstrap.  All you need to do is add this to your code and it will work:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

See it working here:

```css
.button,
button:not([data-filter]):not(.mfp-arrow),
input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #090909;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  line-height: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 20px 41px;
  margin-top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  -o-transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button:before,
button:not([data-filter]):not(.mfp-arrow):before,
input[type="button"]:before,
input[type="reset"]:before,
input[type="submit"]:before {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.2);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



       <section class="our-news section-margin">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="one-title" data-dsn-animate="up">
                    <div class="title-sub-container">
                        <p class="title-sub">Frequently Asked Questions</p>
                    </div>
                    <h2 class="title-main">What you need to know</h2>
                </div>

            <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                  <h2 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                      Collapsible Group Item #1
                    </button>
                  </h2>
                </div>

                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're not importing everything you need to be into your HTML file.

Documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/
You need all 4 links and the last 2 before the first two

Also, you don't have a button class. If you just want to access buttons, just use

```
button {
}
```

Not

```
.button {
}
```